ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server: SSL Provider
I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server database which is in a Windows Server machine from a Linux arm based server, I'm using Python as programing language and SQLAlchemy and this is the code I'm using to get the connection:
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

load_dotenv()

class Database:
    server = str(os.getenv('DB_HOST')) + "," + str(os.getenv('DB_PORT'))
    database = os.getenv('DB_DATABASE')
    username = os.getenv('DB_USER')
    password = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
    params = ('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 For SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + str(database) +
              ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password+";Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
    engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
    def connection(self):
        db = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        conn = db()
        return conn


All the data authentication data is in the .env file
And when I try to connect to the server I get this response:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

I tried to install the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server but it is not supported on arm Linux os I don't know what to do.
The version of SQL Server is

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) Jun 12 2012 13:05:25 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ).


Your version of SQL Server is severely out of date. As the version information states, build 11.0.2218.0 was released in June 2012 (over 12 years ago); it was one of the first security updates for 2012. Such an old version doesn't support TLS1.2, which your client will be trying to use; support for TLS 1.2 was added in January 2016 (which is still 8.5 years ago). Forcing <TLS1.2 is not a solution; that your other clients are using it is as good as sending your data unencrypted in modern times as TLS1.1 (and older) are no longer considered secure.
You need to get your instance updated to the latest SP, CU, and security patch; this will solve the error you are facing.
This, however, isn't the end of the story. 2012 is end of life, and has been for a couple years now. You need to, therefore, get your instance upgraded to a supported version as well (2022). As you're using Enterprise, then that is going to be a far from cheap purchase, but something that needs doing.
Also, while you're there, find someone else to be responsible for keeping that service up to date. If your company can afford Enterprise, they can afford to pay someone to keep your server(s) up to date. Not installing any updates in 12 years is shameful. Running end of life software for a (short) period of time while finalising budgets, downtime, workload and availability is something that, though far from ideal, does happen. Not installing any updates for 12 years can only be described as severe negligence.

I know, thanks for your advices and to make it worst that it is, i asked them if is posible to update the version of SQL Server to another more recent or at least install the security updates and the guy that manages the servers and networking here told me that they are using a pirated version of SQL Server :C, im currently convincing the boss to migrate all the system to a cloud service because they have everything here in local servers and as you can imagine, the servers are pure crap

Oh great... Yeah... No offence to you, I have no respect for your employer... That's outright theft...

Im waiting fot the end of month and im leaving, im working here as trainee because im still in the SE carreer but im done with this people haha
